# Model is NULL in Ajax POST to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action

I have a simple model and view. THough, the modelbinder seems to fail when trying to bind my model because I always receive NULL into my controller action. What am I doing wrong?

Razor code:

```
@model BikeSharing.Views.Shared.Widgets.Popups.LoginInputModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login",null, new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "login-partial-update",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}, new { id = "js-form-login" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new {placeholder = "Email address"})
    <div class="errormessage">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Email)
    </div>
    @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new {placeholder = "Password"})
    <div class="errormessage">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)

    </div>
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginInputModel lmod)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // this code is never reached because lmod is always NULL
   }
   return PartialView("Widgets/Popups/_LoginInput", lmod);
}
```

Model code:

```
public class LoginInputModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your email address is required.")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; private set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your password.")]
        [MinLength(6,ErrorMessage = "Your password is too short.")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Your password is too long.")]
        public string Password { get; private set; }

        public LoginInputModel()
        {

        }

        public LoginInputModel(string email, string password)
        {
            Email = email;
            Password = password;
        }
    }
```

The form submit is done via jquery-unobtrusive-ajax and `Ajax.BeginForm()`
I am only firing it via `$('#js-form-login').submit();`

Rendered HTML in browser:

```
<form action="/Home/Login" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#login-partial-update" id="js-form-login" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
   <input data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="Your email address is required." id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email address" type="text" value="">
   <div class="errormessage">
      <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
   </div>
   <input data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="Your password is too long." data-val-maxlength-max="50" data-val-minlength="Your password is too short." data-val-minlength-min="6" data-val-required="Please provide your password." id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
   <div class="errormessage">
     <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: how you are submitting the form???

Comment: I edited my question with that info :)

Comment: just check the rendered html in browser console...the fields should be inside form closing and opening tags.

Comment: That is the case. See my post

Comment: Why are you submitting using `$('#js-form-login').submit();`? Does it work with a normal `<input type="submit" />` inside the form?

Comment: post your model class also..

Comment: Do you see the form request being made on the Network Tab in the browsers Developer Tools.

Comment: @Kartikeya I updated my post with it.

Comment: @Oliver I do. It comes to my backend fine, but the model is just null

Comment: You don't have any public setters on your properties! How do you expect them to bind.

Comment: Ohhh....God...yes i agree with stephen ... you have made setters as private...that is the problem..

Comment: I didn't see that while copy pasting. It's indeed the error

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `FormBody` prefix to hint to the ModelBinder to look in the POST body.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginInputModel lmod)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // this code is never reached because lmod is always NULL
   }
   return PartialView("Widgets/Popups/_LoginInput", lmod);
}
```